# Passing entity context into class constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm still a little new to Entity Framework so I'm still working through some of the basics.  I have a data access layer that's doing most of the heavy lifting.  However, as I'm learning about EF and contexts I'm realizing how important it is to maintain one context especially when you're trying to update children of an instance of a entity object.  So my plan is to create the context on the front end and pass it into the data layer.

Front End:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        supplyEntities ctx = new supplyEntities();
        GroupsClass gc = new GroupsClass(ctx);
     }
}
```

Data Layer:

```
public class GroupsClass
{
    private supplyEntities context;

    public GroupsClass(supplyEntities ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    public List<group> GetAllGroups()
    {
        context.do stuff;
    }
}
```

It errors on "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property".  What am I missing?  Or, should I be doing this a different way?

Comment: if you double click the error, where does it take you?  I can't see how you're getting that error from the code you've shown...

Comment: That code does not look like it would throw an error as is.  Maybe it is a situation where something its looking for an empty constructor on your `GroupsClass`?

Comment: The error occurs on ctx when I create the instance of GroupsClass in pageload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is strange in sense that it tells about something that happens in static method. You cannot use instance-level member when running inside a static method, that's what this error means. Can you paste the exact code in which error is reported?

And aside from the error, one piece of an advice. Do not create data context on the front end. That means that front end is irrevocably tied to the context. There is no way to mock it, there is no way to test it automatically, no way to replace it with any other implementation, etc.

Comment: Which method is static?  I didn't define any as explicitly static.

Comment: That was my question: which method is static? So, the error occurs in static code. What is the exact line on which the error is reported?

Comment: I understand where you're coming from about not creating a data context on the front end.  I've actually avoided doing it for the entire project.  However, I'm just getting too many issues with missmatched contexts and trying to juggle them all between all the entity object data classes it just seemed to make life easier.  I could create a context creation class with just one property in it.  Then I create an instance of that class and use that instance to pass into the other classes...

Comment: The error occurs on ctx when I create the instance of GroupsClass in pageload.

Comment: That's OK, just wandering now - is this a compile time error or run time error? This problem tickles me because it looks like I'm missing something as well.

Comment: You don't have any initializers in GroupClass code, like fields instantiated before the constructor? Is this constructor code complete? This error also occurs if some fields used by the constructor are initialized outside of the constructor.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what happened or why but I started from scratch and just created a new class and it seems to be working.

@sysexpand we talked about not creating the context on the front end.  How would you suggest I do this if I'm going to be making calls across multiple classes which previously all had their own context?

Comment: In my designs, UI and even models are not aware of data context. Data context is hidden as private inside services, which can either be proper service classes, or a set of unit of work classes, or something similar. This is a little bit different from what books typically say (e.g. that UoW should receive repository, and repository should have hard-coded dependency on particular data context). Anyway, this principle went exceptionally good in one relatively large project that I'm working on.

Comment: I understand the concept of the data layer being siloed from the other layers and I try to adhere to that.  My problem is, if I have a class for every entity object and a context in the class, I get conflicting context issues when I try to save an entity object as a child of another entity object.